# How to copy a complete directory recursively to a remote server in Python (paramiko) using SCP or SSH?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko, scp

I have a directory containing some files and sub-directories on my local machine that is generated by a daily Python script running. And then I want to copy all those generated files in a directory to the server and then run some series of commands on it by ssh using python package paramiko.

I want to add little code to securely copy that entire directory and files and sub-directories inside it to to my server over SSH/SCP using the paramiko package of python. I can send the individual files using the same but unable to send the entire directory and its content using paramiko. It gives me IOError saying it's a directory.

```
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'temp'
```

Here is the my code:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
from scp import SCPClient

class SSh(object):

    def __init__(self, address, username, password, port=22):
        print "Connecting to server."
        self._address = address
        self._username = username
        self._password = password
        self._port = port
        self.sshObj = None
        self.connect()
        self.scp = SCPClient(self.sshObj.get_transport())

    def sendCommand(self, command):
        if(self.sshObj):
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.sshObj.exec_command(command)
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                # Print data when available
                if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                    prevdata = b"1"
                    while prevdata:
                        prevdata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                        alldata += prevdata

                    print str(alldata)
        else:
            print "Connection not opened."

    def connect(self):
        try:
            ssh = SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(self._address, port=self._port, username=self._username, password=self._password, timeout=20, look_for_keys=False)
            print 'Connected to {} over SSh'.format(self._address)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            ssh = None
            print "Unable to connect to {} over ssh: {}".format(self._address, e)
            return False
        finally:
            self.sshObj = ssh

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Parse and check the arguments
    ssh = SSh('10.24.143.190', 'username', 'password')
    ssh.scp.put("Valigrind_BB.py") # This works perfectly fine
    ssh.scp.put("temp") # IOError over here Is a directory
    ssh.sendCommand('ls')
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code for SCP, it appears you can pass the parameter "recursive" as a bool to the put() method to specify transferring the contents of a directory recursively. [Here](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py/blob/master/scp.py#L148) is a link to the source code I am talking about. Try changing last part of your code to the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Parse and check the arguments
    ssh = SSh('10.24.143.190', 'username', 'password')
    ssh.scp.put("Valigrind_BB.py") # This works perfectly fine
    ssh.scp.put("temp", recursive=True) # IOError over here Is a directory
    ssh.sendCommand('ls')
```

Also, if you just want to transfer files, you can try rsync as an alternative. The modification to your code above should work though. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes got it after some search. Thanks..!!

Comment: I'm glad that fixed the issue. I'm more familiar with the Paramiko library than the SCP library so I'm not sure if there is another way to to perform the transfer recursively but if that flag fixes it I guess just go with that. Glad I was able to help.